# Como faço para comparar a propriedade de um objeto com uma string?

Tags: php

```
class Alunos{

   public $nome; 

}

$aluno= new Alunos();

$aluno->nome="Pedro";

if(propriedade=="nome")

{

   echo $aluno->nome;

}
```

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo mais claro?

Comment: Eu quero verificar se o índice da propriedade no caso o public $nome é igual a string "nome". Eu n quero o que contem  em nome, e sim o índice, ,que é a palavra nome.

Comment: Explique qual a finalidade pois pode existir diferentes meios de resolver onde um pode ser mais adequado que outro.

Comment: A finalidade é escrever uma linha em um arquivo, separando por virgula.Só que no nome que é o primeiro elemento da linha eu n quero virgula.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o que você precisa é a função [`property_exists`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.property-exists.php). Ela retorna `true` se uma classe ou objeto possui uma determinada propriedade e `false` caso contrário.

```
class Alunos{

   public $nome; 

}

$aluno= new Alunos();

$aluno->nome="Pedro";

if (property_exists("Alunos", "nome"))
{
   echo $aluno->nome, PHP_EOL; // Pedro
}
```

Ou utilizando o próprio objeto:

```
if (property_exists($aluno, "nome"))
{
   echo $aluno->nome, PHP_EOL; // Pedro
}
```